# IsFacing and IsBehind calculations

Tags: c#

I'm looking for better way to calculate if one object facing another or one is behind another. So far I've been able to create this but it seems to not working 100% correctly :(

I also think it should be in radians rather then degrees.

```
public static float GetAngle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float xDiff = x2 - x1;
    float yDiff = y2 - y1;
    var angle = RadianToDegree((float)Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff));

    if (angle < 0)
        return 360 + angle;

        return angle;
    }

public static bool IsFacing(Point obj, float rotationAngle, Point target, float arcDegree = 180)
{
    var angleBetweenPoints = GetAngle(obj, target);

    return rotationAngle >= angleBetweenPoints - arcDegree / 2 && rotationAngle <= angleBetweenPoints + arcDegree / 2;
}

public static bool IsBehind(Point obj, float rotationAngle, Point target, float arcDegree = 180)
{
    var angleBetweenPoints = GetAngle(obj, target);
    var backViewAngle = rotationAngle > 180 ? rotationAngle - 180 : 180 - rotationAngle;
    return backViewAngle >= angleBetweenPoints - arcDegree / 2 && backViewAngle <= angleBetweenPoints + arcDegree / 2;
}
```

Comment: Could you include some sample inputs where your code is misbehaving (with your and expected results).

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like your problem is in the test of `rotationAngle` vs `angleBetweenPoints` in the `IsFacing()` method.

Given:

```
rotationAngle = 0, angleBetweenPoints = 350, arcDegree = 180
```

then the test will be:

```
test = 0 >= (350 - 180 / 2) && 0 <= (350 + 180 / 2)
     = 0 >= 260 && 0 <= 440
     = false
```

This will happen fairly often, and is due to the use of the range [0..360] for your angles.  While this is useful in some cases, this is not one of those cases.  Far more useful here is to get the difference in the heading and target angles in the range [-180..180], then the comparison to `arcDegree` becomes much simpler.

Try this:

```
// Adjust a value to fit in the specified range
public static float Clamp(float v, float low, float high)
{
    float range = high - low;
    float modifier = ((int)((v - low) / range) - (v < low ? 1 : 0)) * range;
    v -= modifier;
    return v;
}

// Get the angle between a point+heading and another point
// Returns an angle in the range (-180..180) where:
//  res < 0     target clockwise from heading
//  res == 0    target at heading
//  res > 0     target counter-clockwise from heading
static float RelativeAngle(float heading, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    // get angle between points in world coordinates
    float angle = RadianToDegree((float)Math.Atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1));
    // adjust to local coordinates and normalize
    return Clamp(angle - heading, -180, 180);
}

public static bool IsFacing(Point obj, float rotationAngle, Point target, float arcDegree = 180)
{
    var angleBetweenPoints = RelativeAngle(rotationAngle, obj.x, obj.y, target.x, target.y);
    return angleBetweenPoints >= -(arcDegree / 2) && angleBetweenPoints <= (arcDegre / 2);
}
```